# Unable to login with SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server

With Windows authentication, I am able to connect to SQL Server. Then I change password for `sa`, then I try to connect with SQL Server authentication, but I get an error

> Login failed for user sa.

Thanks

Comment: The SQL Server error log will detail the reason for the failed login but it is likely the server is configured to allow only Windows authentication as @EddyYoung suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are entering the correct password and it still does not work, you need to [enable SQL Server Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode).